# Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath from URL

Tags: image, zend-framework, url, pdf

I'm using a script that generates a PNG image based on a URL parameter `image_id`.
For example: `http://www.example.com/image.php?image_id=G554jGTT`

Now I want to place that image in a pdf like so:

```
$imagepath = "www.example.com/image.php?id=" . $id;
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imagepath);
```

When I use a local file all goes well, but when I use an URL I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'Cannot create image resource. File not found.' in E:<...>\library\Zend\Pdf\Resource\ImageFactory.php:38`

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this using `Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath`. The reason is that the `ImageFacotry` expects a file. And it uses `is_file` method to check if file exists. However, `is_file` function does not necessarily work with remote files.

One way to overcome this problem would be to download the image and save it under temporary name, and this temporary file then put into `Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath`. To download and save the file, you could use, e.g. `file_put_contents('./tempname',file_get_contents($imagepath))`. Off course, the tempname should be random and it should be removed afterwards.