# Issue with image url in magento

Tags: zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

I have to generate pdf of product images using zend_PDF. I have tried the following code

```
 $path=$this->getImageUrl($_product) 

 $imagePath=$path;
 $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imagePath);
 $page->drawImage($image, 40,764,240, 820);
```

This does not work. Can any one help me how to give url of product images properly.

Comment: I am not sure, that Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath() accepts urls instead the location of the file on your hard drive. Where your image is placed in your hard drive? Is it in media folder of your Magento installation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it's located in media folder of magento installation the folder where all product's images are saved.

Comment: I have already tried the solution specified in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288340/get-original-image-url-magento-1-6-1-0. It still doesn't work. Can you provide me some other solution.

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018217/issue-with-image-url-in-magento#autocomment16041310
OR
http://sapnandu-magento.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-get-product-image-in-magento.html

Comment: What is the returned path to the image? What are the dimensions of the  PDF document? Which version of Magento do you use is it 1.7?

Comment: The statement $path=$this->getImageUrl($_product) returns  "http://localhost/magento1.7/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg" to $path and it doesn't work.But I want that Url should be like this" C:/wamp/www/magento1.7/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg" Can you please provide me some solution of how to get physical path of media folder in magento1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. on this line.

```
$path = $this->getImageUrl($_product);
```

Try this the correct one:

```
$path = $_product->getImageUrl();
```

and see this [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016962/zend-pdf-imageimagewithpath-from-url)